# Operator overloading in js?

Tags: javascript

Is there anything that allows for overloading some of the more common operators in javascript? For example, taking an example from python to overload the `>>`:

```python
d1 = {'a':{'b':{'c':42}}}
class Perhaps:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self): return str(self.value) # for direct value shorthand
    def __rshift__(self, func):
        if self.value is not None:
            return Perhaps(func(self.value))
        else:
            return self
Perhaps(d1) >> (lambda d:d['a']) >> (lambda d:d['b']) >> (lambda d:d['c'])
# 42
```

Is the following the closest we can come in javascript?

```js
let d1 = {'a':{'b':{'c':42}}};
class Perhaps {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    rshift(func) {
        if (this.value !== null) {
            return new Perhaps(func(this.value));
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
console.log((new Perhaps(d1)).rshift(d => d.a)
                             .rshift(d => d.b)
                             .rshift(d => d.c).value);
```

Comment: No, there isn't anything like this in JS. Sorry.

Comment: @Barmar ok thanks, is the above the closest approximation then? Or are there other ways to emulate that python-like behavior?

Comment: It seems like it. Operator overloading basically just translates the operator into that type of method.